# sympy reach the specific polinomial expression from roots

Tags: python, sympy

I have the polynomial :
x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1.
We can factorize the expression below like:
(x^2+ax+1)(x^2+bx+1).
I found 4 roots by:
`solve((x**4)+(x**3)+(x**2)+(x)+1)`
Is there any way to obtain the expression above?
Thx to all

Comment: Absolutely yes!!!Taking into account that this particular polinomial function grows-up when I manipulate an integral that sympy doen't do.Thanks again.

Comment: I did it!Thanks, however they are both useful to reach the goal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polynomial does not factor over the rationals. It completely factorises over any domain containing all 4 roots. In this case the quadratic factorisation that you show is the factorisation in `QQ<sqrt(5)>`:

```
In [15]: x = Symbol('x')

In [16]: p = x**4 + x**3 + x**2 + x + 1

In [17]: p
Out[17]: 
 4    3    2        
x  + x  + x  + x + 1

In [18]: roots(p)
Out[18]: 
⎧                 ________                      ________                      ________                      ________   ⎫
⎪  1   √5        ╱ √5   5        1   √5        ╱ √5   5        √5   1        ╱ 5   √5        √5   1        ╱ 5   √5    ⎪
⎨- ─ + ── - ⅈ⋅  ╱  ── + ─ : 1, - ─ + ── + ⅈ⋅  ╱  ── + ─ : 1, - ── - ─ - ⅈ⋅  ╱  ─ - ── : 1, - ── - ─ + ⅈ⋅  ╱  ─ - ── : 1⎬
⎪  4   4      ╲╱   8    8        4   4      ╲╱   8    8        4    4     ╲╱   8   8         4    4     ╲╱   8   8     ⎪
⎩                                                                                                                      ⎭

In [19]: factor(p, extension=sqrt(5))
Out[19]: 
⎛ 2     ⎛1   √5⎞    ⎞ ⎛ 2     ⎛1   √5⎞    ⎞
⎜x  + x⋅⎜─ - ──⎟ + 1⎟⋅⎜x  + x⋅⎜─ + ──⎟ + 1⎟
⎝       ⎝2   2 ⎠    ⎠ ⎝       ⎝2   2 ⎠    ⎠
```

You can get there from the roots like:

```
In [21]: r1, r2, r3, r4 = roots(p)

In [22]: expand((x-r1)*(x-r2))
Out[22]: 
 2   x   √5⋅x    
x  + ─ + ──── + 1
     2    2      

In [23]: expand((x-r3)*(x-r4))
Out[23]: 
 2   √5⋅x   x    
x  - ──── + ─ + 1
      2     2
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar.The problem grows-up when I try to solve a particular integral in Sympy: (sinh(x))/((exp5*x)-1). The solution pass accross this polinomial function because the tool doesn't solve this integral and I must make the intermedial steps

Answer (score 0):

The following approach creates an equation for each coefficient of the polynomials:

```py
from sympy import Eq, solve, Poly
from sympy.abc import x, a, b

p1 = Poly((x ** 2 + a * x + 1) * (x ** 2 + b * x + 1), x)
p2 = Poly(x ** 4 + x ** 3 + x ** 2 + x + 1, x)
solve([Eq(p1_coef, p2_coef) for p1_coef, p2_coef in zip(p1.all_coeffs(), p2.all_coeffs())])
```

This leads to two solutions (with swapped signs):

```py
[{a: 1/2 - sqrt(5)/2, b: 1/2 + sqrt(5)/2},
 {a: 1/2 + sqrt(5)/2, b: 1/2 - sqrt(5)/2}]
```